# I am having trouble getting a text file to an array, and then sorting the array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, numbers, text-files

I need to read a saved text file into an array, and then sort it numerically. This is rather hard as the text file is :

```
10 First name:bob
30 first name:sam
```

And so on. It is not sorted this way, it is saved in the text file in the structure of score "first name" & first name. I have to sort it numerically showing highest to lowest. I have tried sort.array. But this is for only sorting an array that only has words, alphabetically. I have tried other processes but they don't seem to work. Can someone help me. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this carefully: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
    Dim DataFileName As String = "C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Data.txt"
    Dim SortedByScore = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines(DataFileName)
                        Let score = CInt(line.Split(" ")(0))
                        Order By score Descending
                        Select line
    For Each line As String In SortedByScore
        Debug.Print(line.ToString)
    Next
```

Using Array.Sort() with a Comparer:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim DataFileName As String = "C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Data.txt"
    Dim Lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(DataFileName)
    Array.Sort(Lines, AddressOf SortByScore)
    For Each line As String In Lines
        Debug.Print(line.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

For the original format specified in the question as: `10 First name:bob`

```
Private Function SortByScore(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer
    Dim valuesX() As String = x.ToString.Split(" ")
    Dim valuesY() As String = y.ToString.Split(" ")
    Return CInt(valuesY(0)).CompareTo(CInt(valuesX(0)))
End Function
```

If the format is actually: `bob{vbTab}score :10`, then try:

```
Private Function SortByScore(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer
    Dim valuesX() As String = x.ToString.Split(":")
    Dim valuesY() As String = y.ToString.Split(":")
    Return CInt(valuesY(1)).CompareTo(CInt(valuesX(1)))
End Function
```

Comment: Private Sub Btn_Averages3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cmb_Averages3.Click
            Dim DataFileName As String = "G:\ControlleAssesmentClass\Class3\average3.txt"
            Dim Lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(DataFileName)
            Array.Sort(Lines, AddressOf SortByScore)
            For Each line As String In Lines
                Debug.Print(line.ToString)
            Next

Comment: Private Function SortByScore(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer
        Dim valuesX() As String = x.ToString.Split(" ")
        Dim valuesY() As String = y.ToString.Split(" ")
        Return CInt(valuesY(0)).CompareTo(CInt(valuesX(0)))
    End Function

Comment: it says An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Conversion from string "12 heavy" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: and then An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Failed to compare two elements in the array.

Comment: but the text file is set up as                                            "11 ligh" then a tab 
"12 heavy"

Comment: How did Tabs come into the mix?...they weren't mentioned before.  Is it a Space or a Tab between the score and the name?

Comment: the code for it is : Txt_StudentFirstName.Text & vbTab & "score :" & score.ToString

Comment: ?! Space and vbTab are clearly not the same thing.   If you have a Tab in there then Split() using Tab instead?....

Comment: sorry, im just a beginner, so how would i do that on the code

Comment: Confused now.  Originally you said the format was: `10 First name:bob`.  Is it actually? `bob{vbTab}score : 10`.